# Generate executable jar with vmarguments

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am generating a jar file as usual in eclipse, right click->export->as executable jar file-> point the filesystem exit->export

To execute i need to use a really big command 
java -Djava.library.path="C:\works\copaWeb\ChangeOrder\lib" -jar -d32 updateOrder.jar

This command -Djava.library.path="C:\works\copaWeb\ChangeOrder\lib" i use to load a .dll file, i want to generate a jar that user can just double click and run.

Comment: Doesn't batch file suit your needs? It can be just clicked, but you will have to have it along with your jar (and libraries if you have them)

Comment: no its not @Marged, i dont want the user typing jva -jar etc... just double click, and setProperty does not work in this case.

Comment: Look further down, there is information how this can be achieved without setting the -D

Comment: Resolved my problem using a bat file as @RomanPuchkovskiy suggested